# replace-regexp-in-string stops replacement with "^."?

Tags: regular-expressions

I've encountered a wierd situation when trying to match the first character of a string using a regex with alternatives.  It seems that replacement stops when matching a single character using a period at the start of the string, but not for slightly different patterns.

Desired behavior:

"foo bar" -> "Foo Bar"

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
   "^.\\| ."
   #'upcase
   "foo bar")
> "Foo bar"
```

Notice that replacement stops and doesn't capitalize the 'b' in 'bar'.  However:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
   "^f\\| ."
   #'upcase
   "foo bar")
> "Foo Bar"

(replace-regexp-in-string
   "^.o\\| ."
   #'upcase
   "foo bar")
> "FOo Bar"

(replace-regexp-in-string
   "^..\\| ."
   #'upcase
   "foo bar")
> "FOo Bar"
```

I have tried parenthesizing all combinations of the alternatives to no effect.

I'm not concerned about beginning of string vs beginning of line ('\`' vs '^'), but FWIW this odd behavior is consistent with both patterns.

I'm observing this behavior with both emacs 24.5.1 and 25.0.95.1.

Comment: Take a look at it's implementation, where you'll immediately see why this is happening.  I think, it can be considered a bug.

Comment: I did not see immediately why this is happening, so spoiler alert, here's why : in the current implementation, the regexp is matched first against the whole string (that's normal and ok), then once again, but only against the substring that matched. This is an optimisation which leads to the bug because the substring that matched is " b" which is matched by "^.", so only the space character gets upcased. Could you please `M-x report-emacs-bug` ?

Comment: Thank you. I was just ducking behind the `immediate`, because for some reason I couldn't be bothered earlier with explaining it, like you just did.

Comment: I think this might be another case of [Bug #15107](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15107 "replace-regexp-in-string wrong on \\`")

Comment: Not addressing the bug (if that's what it is), but just noting that you could (I think should) use `capitalize`, not `replace-regexp-in-string`: `(capitalize "foo bar") => "Foo Bar"`

Comment: Again, not addressing the bug, I think `"\\<."` may be the regexp you want. (That is: beginning of word followed by character). `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\<." #'upcase "foo bar") => "Foo Bar"`

Comment: I should have stepped into the function :-)  My assumption was that I had my chopsticks wrong in some form or another an the library is correct (it has been around for a while after all).  I ported a small string case library to elisp and wanted to keep implementation details visible, so `capitalize` was not an option although probably a correct one.  I had split the `replace-rexexp-in-string` call with two (one with each alternative), but just went back and applied @PhilHudson 's `"\\<."` suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's consensus that the observed behavior is buggy and not user error / an expected limitation of regexps in emacs.

I mentioned this discussion and submitted a regression test for the bug on debbugs:
[GNU bug #15107 "24.3; replace-regexp-in-string wrong on `](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15107)

One solution for those seeking one in the interim:  If the replacements do not interact with the pattern itself, the replacement may be split at the pattern alternatives.  For example:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "^." #'upcase
 (replace-regexp-in-string " ." #'upcase "foo bar"))
```

Ultimately I changed my regexp to use the word boundary character `\\<` to yield the pattern `"\\<."`
In my particular case I could have replaced the whole thing with `#'capitalize`.